# JS Object {} advanced filtering

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a huge chunk of data directly from the database, that data is stored in a JS object : {}, however I'm unable to use built-in JS's .filter function.
Avoid arrow functions as I'm using Vue.JS.

Example of JS Object:

```
0:
brand: "Brand A"
compatibilitySetIds:Array(3)
createdAt:"2018-08-13T09:07:50.772Z"
deletedAt:null
id:"e7915261-677d-4527-90c6-09b5170afca8"
model:"Model-1"
series:null
type:"A"
updatedAt:"2018-08-13T09:07:50.772Z"
1:
brand: "Brand B"
compatibilitySetIds:Array(3)
createdAt:"2018-08-13T09:07:50.772Z"
deletedAt:null
id:"e7915261-677d-4527-90c6-09b5170afca8"
model:"Model-51"
series:"S02"
type:"B"
updatedAt:"2018-08-13T09:07:50.772Z"
```

I need to be able to:

1. Filter by Model
2. Preferably filter also by Brand/Series/Type
3. Be able to sort asc/desc in all fields

What I currently have (works)

```
  computed: {
    filteredEquipment: function() {
      if (this.search.selected === '' || !this.search.selected) {
        return this.equipmentItems;
      } else {
        const model = this.search.selected;
        console.log(model);
        const filtered = this.equipmentItems.filter(function(item) {
          return item.model === model;
        });
        return filtered;
      }
    },
  },
```

PS.
Using Vue-JS along with TypeScript.

PPS.
I must filter on the client side, not on the server side.

Comment: Please provide better example of the data object you are using.

Comment: Why you don't store those objects in an array, if their indexes are 0 and 1?

Comment: Your example object is not valid JS.

Comment: When you say that you're "unable to use built-in JS's .filter function", do you mean that you're simply not in an environment that supports it?  Or are you saying that you couldn't get it to work by using `.filter()`?

Comment: And your narrative says, "Avoid arrow functions as I'm using Vue.JS."... but you are using arrow functions in the example of what you currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your data items are wrapped inside an array, since you have object keys "0" and "1", which seem to be indexes to me. Also you use filter yourself in your code.

You have a couple of choices here to use `.filter()`.
So you can choose which best suites your coding style.

```js
const data = [
  {
    brand: "Brand A",
    compatibilitySetIds: [],
    createdAt:"2018-08-13T09:07:50.772Z",
    deletedAt:null,
    id:"e7915261-677d-4527-90c6-09b5170afca8",
    model:"Model-1",
    series:null,
    type:"A",
    updatedAt:"2018-08-13T09:07:50.772Z"
  },
  {
    brand: "Brand B",
    compatibilitySetIds: [],
    createdAt:"2018-08-13T09:07:50.772Z",
    deletedAt:null,
    id:"e7915261-677d-4527-90c6-09b5170afca8",
    model:"Model-51",
    series:"S02",
    type:"B",
    updatedAt:"2018-08-13T09:07:50.772Z"
  }
];
//Specific one liner to filter all Model-1 models.
const AllModel_1Items = data.filter( item => item.model === 'Model-1' );
console.log( AllModel_1Items );
// Generic function with 3 parameters:
const filterProperty = ( source, property, value ) => source.filter( item => item[ property ] === value );
const allTypeA = filterProperty( data, 'type', 'A' );
console.log( allTypeA );
// Generic function usable with .filter()
const byProperty = ( property, value ) => item => item[ property ] === value;
const allBrandA = data.filter( byProperty( 'brand', 'Brand A' ));
console.log( allBrandA );
```

These functions can filter any property. Sorting asc/desc is just `.reverse()` the array after `.sort()`.

If for some reason arrows can't be used or filter cannot be used, the same structure can be applied to a simple for loop to mimic `.filter()`.

But since you use both .filter() and arrows in your own code, I'll assume that you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(dbObject)` this will convert into array. Then you should be able to use just all the other `filter` and etc. methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop for read array, and add conditions for filter your data, for example:

```js
let dataFiltered = [];
let data = [
{
  brand: "Brand A",
  compatibilitySetIds:Array(3),
  createdAt:"2018-08-13T09:07:50.772Z",
  deletedAt:null,
  id:"e7915261-677d-4527-90c6-09b5170afca8",
  model:"Model-1",
  series:null,
  type:"A",
  updatedAt:"2018-08-13T09:07:50.772Z",
},
{
  brand: "Brand B",
  compatibilitySetIds:Array(3),
  createdAt:"2018-08-13T09:07:50.772Z",
  deletedAt:null,
  id:"e7915261-677d-4527-90c6-09b5170afca8",
  model:"Model-51",
  series:"S02",
  type:"B",
  updatedAt:"2018-08-13T09:07:50.772Z",
}];

//Use a loop for read array
data.forEach(function(item){
  if(item.model === 'Model-1'){
    //Add conditions after push item to dataFilter
    dataFiltered.push(item);
  }
})

console.log(dataFiltered);//In dataFilter is data filtered
```